# How to pick a good threshold for multimodal histograms

Tags: histogram, threshold, mode

I am trying to do multi-modal detection in a vote map (histogram) however, side lobes obviously cause some false peaks. So using mean shift will not do as it will find all of the local maxima. So I thought I could first threshold the histogram and then apply mean shift.

However, I am struggling to find a suitable threshold value (derivable rather than a hard value). This is because the data can range from very close to zero to about 19 or 20. It is a 480x640 vote space.

For this reason, the mean is inappropriate as it is usually a very small number as the number of tiny peaks is generally much higher than the true peaks. Similarly standard deviation is quite small. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is a "vote map"?  Are you distinguishing it from a histogram or equating it with one? (If the former, could you post an example?)  Do you have available *only* the vote map or do you have access to the underlying data?

Comment: @whuber I am equating them, it is a 2-D histogram. I do have access to the underlying data.

Comment: @Aly: my problem is similar to what you described. How do you calculate the "vote map"? Why do you use the histogram of the map?